# How can I get specific row number containing the value by using formula countif () in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a column "C" with different values on it. Now I'm trying put the condition like =COUNTIF(C:C = "text", ...) then i need to operate with that exact row containing that text. How can I get that row number containg that cell?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({ROW(C2:C),C2:C},"select Col1 where Col2='text'",0))
```

Alternative:

```
=FILTER(ROW(C:C),C:C="text")
```

Comment: how to get all row index containing that value? since this function only shows one

Comment: Modified. Please check.